# @stencil/angular-output-target: Getting "Module has no exported member" error for an Interface I use on one of my components

Tags: angular, monorepo, nrwl-nx, stenciljs

I need some advice on this because I'm not sure what to do.
Here goes:

I got an NX monorepo (not necessarily relevant). I'm looking at a component library, an Angular wrapper for that component library and an Angular app that will consume the components wrapped.

I got a StencilJS component that makes use of an interface:

**my-nx-workspace/packages/component-lib/src/components/dropdown-group/dropdown-group.tsx**

```
import { RequestedItem } from '../../services/interfaces/requested-item';

export class DrowpdownGroup { 
    ...props;

    @Event()
    myEvent: EventEmitter<RequestedItem>

    doCoolStuffOnChange(e: CustomEvent): void {
        // doing cool stuff
        myEvent.emit()
    }

}
```

And the interface:

**my-nx-workspace/packages/component-lib/src/services/interfaces/requested-item.ts**

```
export interface RequestedItem {
    // some fields
}
```

I have multiple interfaces and in the folder I got an **intex.ts** file that exports them all like so:

**my-nx-workspace/packages/component-lib/src/services/interfaces/index.ts**

```
export * from './requested-item';
//other exports;
```

Everything cool so far.
I punch a build on this.

> build component-lib

Because I'm trying to wrap it for Angular and I got the configs in **stencil.config** it's going to generate a new lib on this path:
**my-nx-workspace/packages/component-lib-angular**.
And it does, very cool, very nice.

### Problem comes here:

**my-nx-workspace/packages/component-lib-angular/src/generated/directives/proxies.ts**
(this file is auto generated by the build above and contains directives so I can go into my actual Angular project, import, and use the StencilJS wrapped component freely )

```
import { RequestedItem } from '@my-nx-workspace/component-lib';

...some components of mine;

import type { RequestedItem as IDropdownRequestedItem } from '@my-nx-workspace/component-lib';
// ERROR HERE!

...the dropdown declaration and everything

...other components of mine
```

Finally...

The path to the Angular App that consumes these directives:

**my-nx-workspace/packages/angular-app**

When I execute

> build angular-app

It comes back to me with a "build failed" citing this:

> **my-nx-workspace/packages/component-lib-angular/src/generated/directives/proxies.ts: 187:15** - **error** TS2305: Module **'"@my-nx-workspace/component-lib"'** has no exported member **'RequestedItem'**

Any insights are welcome, thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this?

Comment: did you find answer? or did you do anything differently to overcome this issue?

Comment: @NimittShah, I had a similar issue. Stencil couldnt convert the type properly of EventEmiter<RequestItem>. Once I passed in the object properties instead, like EventEmitter<{string, string, number}>, it worked.

Comment: @user3837019 - for now I have fixed it using `EventEmitter<any>` instead of using `EventEmiter<RequestItem>` with todo task.